# Git workflow for compile machine

Tags: git

I work on a large piece of software that takes a long time to compile. I frequently find myself developing locally and then compiling/running on a beefy remote machine. Git makes this all very easy: I commit locally and then pull that branch on a git repo on the remote. Unfortunately, I make mistakes when I code and frequently find myself making commits to fix typos and other small errors that showed up during compilation. These micro commits add up and clutter my logs. I'm looking for a way I can do something like this:

```
#local> git commit -m "My useful commit message and the bulk of my commit"

#remote> git pull local development_branch
#remote> *compile my code and get a stupid error*

#local> *fix error*
#local> git add *fixed file*
#local> git commit --amend

#remote> *force an update to remote that causes it to look like master*
```

So, I'm looking for a command that does that last step, which is updating my remote to look like my local branch after I've amended the commit. The current way I do this is by doing

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git pull local development_branch
```

This works, but seems really ugly. Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Though it's not related to the question about git: if your program is taking such a long time to compile, might you not save a lot of time using `make` or something like it to only recompile the files which have changed?

Comment: Don't interpret this as being sarcastic or snarky, because I'm genuinely curious.  Is there a reason why you can't divide up the compilation into discrete units that can be built individually?  It should be possible to do what you're asking, but this seems like a compelling reason to re-examine your development process.

Comment: You are probably aware of it, but just in case not, there is a  category of software created especially for your problem: continuous integration. Such as [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org).

Comment: Just want to address the comments here. I am using scons to build (which only recompiles changed files, but takes forever to figure out what files are changed which kind of defeats the purpose). The code is also divided up into ~15 separate libraries (>2million lines of code total), so compilation isn't so bad, but linking takes a long time. I'll look into continuous integration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of "going back in time" and then re-pulling, just reset directly to the remote's position:

```
git fetch local
git reset --hard local/development_branch
```

Comment: This works, and is slightly less convoluted than my current solution. Still, it seems like there might be a better way to do this. I'll mark this solution as correct if I don't get any other good responses. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [precommit hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to test the compilability (is that even a word?) before committing. Hooks are [stored in .git/hooks](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/tips-for-using-a-git-pre-commit-hook/) and are shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
#remote> git pull -uf local development_branch:development_branch
```

It will overwrite current branch (i.e. `development_branch`) by remote counterpart, even if it is not a fast-forward update.

UPDATE:

`-u|--update-head-ok` will grant you updating the branch even it is the `HEAD`.

It seems `fetch` will leave a dirty index, so I replace `fetch` to `pull`.

Comment: The first solution appears not to work when you have development_branch currently checked out on the remote machine (as is nearly always the case in my scenario). At any rate, I've accepted Amber's answer above. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @TimmyJ ah, sorry for not fully testing, I have updated my answer.